# Compiler error while converting a dataframe into a Map in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert the below dataframe: chunkMeta into a Map in scala:

```
tablename  Code
table1      432
table2      567
table3      987

scala> val dataMap = chunkMeta.select($"tablename", $"code".cast("long")).as[(String, Long)].collect.toMap
```

I can see the data if I print the above map:

```
scala> dataMap.foreach(println) => (table1,432)(table2,567)(table3,987)
```

But when I put the same conversion of dataframe into a Map on IntelliJ IDEA, the compiler gives me an error:

```
Cannot resolve overloaded method 'select'
```

build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11" % "provided",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3"
)

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
```

I don't understand why the same statement works on scala REPL but not on IntelliJ. Is there any better way to convert the dataframe to Map ?
Or is this is an bug of the scala compiler ?

Comment: "I don't understand why the same statement works on scala REPL but not on IntelliJ." -> I don't see how this is true. In the REPL you print the contents of `dataMap`, in IntelliJ you invoke `chunkMeta.select`.

Comment: This statement: val dataMap = chunkMeta.select($"tablename", $"code".cast("long")).as[(String, Long)].collect.toMap works on REPL but not on IntelliJ. Thats what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` function to manupulate dataframe objects.

Something like below should work.

```
import spark.implicits._

val chunkMeta = Seq(("table1",432),
      ("table2",567),
      ("table3",987),
      ("table1",789)).
      toDF("tablename", "Code").toDF()

chunkMeta.show()

+---------+----+
|tablename|Code|
+---------+----+
|   table1| 432|
|   table2| 567|
|   table3| 987|
|   table1| 789|
+---------+----+

chunkMeta.printSchema()

root
 |-- tablename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Code: integer (nullable = false)

val df2 = chunkMeta.map(r => (r.getString(0),r.getInt(1)))

df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)

val map1 = df2.collect().toMap
map1.foreach(println)

(table1,789)
(table2,567)
(table3,987)
```

Comment: I tried but getting this compilation error: "No implicits found for parameter evidence$7: Encoder[(String, Int)] " at the line "val df2 = chunkMeta.map(r => (r.getString(0),r.getInt(1)))" Do you suggest any changes to that line ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add import statement. Can you please add `import spark.implicits._` in your code. Please let me know if it didn't work. I have updated my comment laso.